# Disable user input while Sleep() command is active?

Tags: c++, sleep

I can't find a solution to stop this program from quitting if I input something while the Sleep() command is active.

```
cout<<"Start"<<endl;

Sleep(5000);  //<--- if I input anything while this is active the program quits after the time ends

cout<<"End"<<endl;  //this is outputted after Sleep(),but the program quits immediately after it
```

Can I somehow disable user input while Sleep() command is active or should I do something else? Please give me your opinions.

Comment: Maybe add `std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX);` to get any input that's buffered. Hard to say without more code. Or since this looks like Windows, maybe [BlockInput()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646290(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't a complete example. The code shown behaves exactly the same regardless of any input.

Comment: @MSalters The code above is a general example. The problem is that if you use this example in a loop or part of a program... and input anything to the console while Sleep() command is active, the program quits.